# wrong AMD GPU installation in Ubuntu default setting

Tags: 20.04, graphics, brightness, amdgpu

I had Dell precision 3510 with FirePro W5130M AMD graphic card. After installing Ubuntu, My login sometime gives my black screen instead of login. the screen is hesitate when it display a white color (bright increase and decrease).
I used the commend

```
lspci
```

and this appear:

```
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde PRO / Venus LE / Tropo PRO-L [Radeon HD 8830M / R7 250 / R7 M465X] (rev 87)
```

how to remove this display controller. Also, I don't know how to install AMD FirePro W5130M. How to install it ?

thanks

Comment: Nothing wrong there FirePro W5130M AMD is actually a Cape Verde PRO Radeon HD 8830M (GPU Variant=Tropo LE and Graphics Processor: Tropo) Linux does not use the commercial name and uses the actual name of the chipset and manufacturer id.

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: if there is any way that I can uninstall AMD as it's not working properly

Comment: Yes open the additional hardware option and uninstall the 3rd party driver

Comment: thank you for your replay ,,

how to open it?

Comment: https://ibb.co/YpdVGst .. Nothing is there?

Comment: Then you do not have one :) https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-21-20 looks like the one you want.